# Compare three bar and plot a shape (by using plotshape) above or below the middle Candle

Tags: pine-script

I am just starting out learning PineScript and sorry if this question is very elementary.
I want to compare three bars. If the middle bar's high is greater than two others, then plot a shape above it by 'plotshape' command. The problem is that in the code below if the condition is true then a shape is plotted on the first bar. How can I change this code?

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script" , overlay = true)
swing_highs=(high[1]>high[0] and high[1]>high[2]) 
plotshape(swing_highs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the offset will also place the shape above the peak bar.

```
plotshape(not barstate.islast and swing_highs, offset = -1)
```

Before:

[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]